# How to execute a command with one parameter at a time in the *nix shell?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, find, grep

Some commands like svn log, for example will only take one input from the command line, so I can't say `grep 'pattern' | svn log`. It will only return the information for the first file, so I need to execute svn log against each one independently.

I can do this with find using it's exec option:  `find -name '*.jsp' -exec svn log {} \;`. However, grep and find provide differently functionality, and the -exec option isn't available for grep or a lot of other tools.

So is there a generalized way to take output from a unix command line tool and have it execute an arbitrary command against each individual output independent of each other like find does?

Comment: grep -l 'pattern' I presume. See also findrepo: http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/findrepo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is `xargs -n 1`.

```
echo moo cow boo | xargs -n 1 echo
```

outputs

```
moo
cow
boo
```

Answer (score 0):

try xargs:

```
grep 'pattern' | xargs svn log
```

Comment: I voted this back up. Why the downvote? svn log does take more than one argument, and while this answer does not exactly answer the question, it may in fact be a better way to use xargs.

Answer (score 0):

A little one off shell script (using xargs is much better for a one off, that's why it exists)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Shift past argv[0]
shift 1

for file in "$@"
do
        svn log $file
done
```

You could name it 'multilog' or something like that. Call it like this:

`./multilog.sh foo.c abc.php bar.h Makefile`

It allows for a little more sanity when being called by automated build scripts, i.e. test the existence of each before talking to SVN, or redirect each output to a separate file, insert it into a sqlite database, etc.

That may or may not be what you are looking for.